# Refresh behavior when signing into acc from admin

Tags: usability, user-expectation

In my product, there is a feature where an admin can sign into the customer's account and manage their settings. (ex: Admin can sign into user's account and change their name) I currently have the design where the dashboard is exactly the same, with a header on top letting the user know what acc they are signed into and an "X" to leave that account. I am curious about the expected behavior when the user refreshes on this page. Should the admin stay signed into the customer acc, or since it looks like an overlay with the "X" should it close and be back to the admin acc? Here is a rough wireframe of my design: [image]

Comment: *"looks like an overlay"* or *"it's an overlay"*? Two different things and the answers are different as well

Comment: @Devin It looks like an overlay to the user, on the code however, it is not an overlay. The code replaces the entire header/body and the "back to admin" reverts those changes. There is not a second window on top of the other. It does, however, look like an overlay because the "back to admin" button takes you to the page you were on before you signed into the customer acc, simulating an overlay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep the user with the account they were using. This is very common in server panels when using an admin account and acting as another user; if you reload, you'll still be in that user account. Just imagine the chaos if you were taken to your admin account without noticing it!

Another common example is Google Analytics and Google Ads. You may have a master account and then different subaccounts and even properties. When using either a subaccount or a property, you'll always remain in that subaccount until you log out or end the session.